# How can I get the value of a table row in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I have a row in my table called "custom_orders_status" which is a dropdown with 3 options, I want when option1 is selected in my database the column in my view to be red but I can't get that option from database. How do I do that?

```
 @foreach($dataTypeContent as $data)
   <tr class="{{ $data->custom_order_status->option1 ? 'alert alert-danger': '' }}">
```

This is what I tried but it throw me this error:
"Trying to get property 'option1' of non-object"

Comment: Use `dd()` to check if your `$data` has an `option1` data. It's probably null

Comment: my $data has custom_order_status row but I want the value of that row.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It has to be `$data->custom_order_status=='option1'`
That **==** saved me